# UK stock historical data

Tags: data-request, stock-market, financial-markets

Where can I find UK stock data over the last 70-80 years? Preferably adjusted to to the inflation.

Comment: Free sources only? A stock index or individual stock prices?

Comment: Have you considered accepting one of the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more and more free database available. Here are a few that I like:

- [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/): this platform gathers data from many providers. Not all database are free, but there are enough data to play around with. One of the best things about Quandl is the APIs and the Excel macro, which allow you to easly send requests and download data.
- [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/): one of the most popular I guess. It is also possible to use some excel macros to download the data, see for example [this macro](http://investexcel.net/multiple-stock-quote-downloader-for-excel/) from InvestExcel
- [GOOGLEFINANCE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=en): If you like Google Sheets, then the function GOOGLEFINANCE is very handy and works quite well. It allows you to get real time data as well as historical data.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find info on this from 1970s at [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.co.uk)
You must, however, do the adjustment yourself by obtaining the CPI inflation from the web site of Office for national statistics.

Comment: I usually find technical information like the yield. I am interesting in more historical data to show the development of the market.

Comment: You should go to 'Historical Data' link on this web site.